# C++ sorting vector of struct explanation

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I'm working on a student information system so that I have this struct to store student information:

```
struct student_info
{
   string name;
   int id;
   string course;
   int percent;
};
```

I have also made this sorting function:

```
bool sorting(const container &a, const container &b) {
    return a.percent < b.percent;
}
```

Here, I read from a file and store in the struct, push it into the vector of struct and then sort it:

```
student_info raw_data;
vector <student_info> container;

ifstream infile("data.txt");

while(!infile.eof())
{
   infile >> raw_data.name >> raw_data.id >> raw_data.course >> raw_data.percent;  
   container.push_back(raw_data);
}   

sort(container.begin(), container.end(), sorting);
```

Then, I saw this somewhere but it didn't clearly explain why I don't need brackets even though sorting is a function like why is it just `sorting` and not `sorting()` when sort is called?

Comment: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: `sorting` isn't called there, thus no brackets. `std::sort` will call it later.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the function is `sorting`.  The expression `sorting(a, b)` would call `sorting` and return a bool.  The sort routine `std::sort` will call `sorting` that way many times.

The name is not a good one. I would suggest `percent_less_than` rather than 'sorting'.  Furthermore, the parameterization is wrong. It compares the `percent` of students.

```
bool percent_less_than(const student_info &a, const student_info &b) {
    return a.percent < b.percent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Jive Dadson` correctly responded to your question.
You can also use lambda syntax for sorting.

```
sort(container.begin(), container.end(), [=](const student_info &a, const student_info &b) {
    return a.percent < b.percent;
});
```